# Nginx Basic authentification for an upstream location

Tags: nginx, https

i am trying to get a basic authentification in an nginx conf for an upstream.

```
location /movies/ {
    rewrite /movies/(.*)$ /$1 break;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_pass http://jd2movies;
        auth_basic "Administrator Login";
        auth_basic_user_file /root/.htpasswd;
}
```

but i get an "500 Internal Server Error"

How can i achieve this to get it working?

Thanks

Comment: just to make sure since you didn't mention that in your question, did you setup the username and the password properly and do you have their values stored in `/root/.htpasswd` file?

Comment: What is the entry in the error log?

Comment: yes everything is stored. i got it now working there was a permission errror for the file .htpasswd. thanks for helping